# Standard form of trig equations

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The standard form for any trig equation is y=Asin(B(x-D))+C (I'm just using sine in the equation). For the "D" which is the horizontal translation, if D is added does the graph move left or right, likewise when it is subtracted?

Comment: When $D>0$ the graph is moved D units to the right; if $D<0$ the graph is moved $|D|$ units to the left.

Answer (score 0):

> define $f:f(t)=A\sin(Bt)+C$ also define $g:g(t)=f(t-D)$

clearly $g(t)$ has the same value as $f$ evaluated $D$ units to the left of $t$ (i.e. $t-D$), hence $f(t-D)$ has the same value as $g$ evaluated $D$ units to the right of $t-D$ (i.e. $(t-D)+D=t$). Now suppose that $x=t-D$, then $f(x)$ has the same value as $g$ evaluated $D$ units to the right of x. Thus, the graph moves to the right for $D>0$.

Another approach is

$$y = A\sin(B(x-D))+C$$
$$y-C = A\sin(B(x-D))$$
$$\frac{y-C}{A} = \sin(B(x-D))$$
$$\sin^{-1}\bigg(\frac{y-C}{A}\bigg) = B(x-D)$$
$$\frac{1}{B}\sin^{-1}\bigg(\frac{y-C}{A}\bigg) = x-D$$
$$\frac{1}{B}\sin^{-1}\bigg(\frac{y-C}{A}\bigg)+D = x$$
You can easily see what will happen if you start "tweaking" the $D$ parameter. Increasing $D$ will tend to increase $x$ (which is what "moving to the right" means).